# Two PS3 controllers connected via USB identified as one

Tags: usb, gamepad, ps3

I'm currently trying to get 2 PS3 controllers (that are connected via USB) to work on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. For most games this works out-of-the-box but some games such as Shutter identify the two controllers as being only one. I found out that in the "Shatter-case" the "Bus-Vendor-Product-Version" information that is provided by e.g. cat /proc/bus/input/devices is used to identify the gamepad (which is identical for the both controllers):

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=054c Product=0268 Version=0111
N: Name="Sony PLAYSTATION(R)3 Controller"
```

There is a config file for Shatter (~/.sidhe/Shatter/data/profiles/default_plr_profile.xml) that stores the information like this:

```
<singleplayer_controller_guid>gamepad_030000004c0500006802000011010000</singleplayer_controller_guid>
```

Do you have any ideas how I could work around this (maybe changing the "Product"-id or something like that for one controller)?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug in SDL2. GUIDS are generated like this:

http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/a9d1c47bb1aa/src/joystick/linux/SDL_sysjoystick.c#l117

And are used primarily for configuring the controller. However the GUID is only identifying the controller *type* not the actual controller, so two controllers of the same type generate the same GUID, which is not what GUIDs should do.

As for workaround, `xboxdrv` has support for PS3 controllers when connected via USB. In case you prefer Blutooth `xboxdrv` can also emulate a virtual controller on top of a regular one and allows you to fiddle with product, vendor, etc. on the virtual one, see `examples/evdev.xboxdrv`.

Made a bug report: https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2327

Comment: Switching to xboxdrv solved at least part of the problem. The controllers work for most games now (except "Shatter").